# sqrt function doesn't evaluate correct value

Tags: c++

I'm newbie in `C++` and I'm trying to evaluate a square root. I've written the following:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double a;
    a=sqrt(2.0);
    printf("Square root from 2 is %d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

But output is `Square root from 2 is 1719614413`. I really don't understood this. Please explain me.

Comment: Just use `std::cout`. Encoding types in strings without even having type safety is quite honestly pointless imo.

Comment: You used `%d` in your `printf` statement.  Look up the documentation, and then *you* can tell *us* what `%d` is used for, and what you should use instead.

Comment: *"This question was caused by a simple typographical error."* (vtc)

Answer (score 4):

You are using C (which mostly compiles as C++ as well), not C++ and you made a mistake doing so. You can either learn C or use C++, where it's harder to make those mistakes:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double a = std::sqrt(2.0);

    std::cout << "Square root from 2 is " << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Additional explanation:

```
printf("Square root from 2 is %d\n",a);
```

This prints a string and expects an integer (%d) to be passed. You passed a double, wich comes out as garbage. You can use (%lf) for doubles.

Comment: "which comes out as garbage": it's actually undefined behavior.  When there's just one format specifier, this is by far the most frequent effect, but if there had been a `"%s"` specifier later, a crash wouldn't have surprised me.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to stick to our example, please consider using %f rather than %d: